# How can i search by _id's feature in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

For example, I want to update half of data whose _id is an odd number. such as:

```js
db.col.updateMany({"$where": "this._id is an odd number"})
```

Instead of integer, `_id` is mongo's ObejectId  which be regard as hexadecimal "string". It is not supported to code as:

```js
db.col.updateMany(
  {"$where": "this._id % 2 = 1"},
  {"$set": {"a": 1}}
)
```

so, what is the correct format?

And what if molding according to _id？

Answer (score 0):

This operation can also be done using two database calls.

- Get List of _id from collection.
- Push only ODD _id into an array.
- Update the collection.

**Updating the collection:**

```
db.collection.update(
   { _id: { $in: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'] } }, // Array with odd _id
   { $set: { urkey : urValue } }
)
```

Comment: Thank you, That's exactly what I'm doing right now, it does work. But are there any method to match _id(mongo's ObjectId) derectly in mongo's query?